# Component not re rendering when new props available unless realoading the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using react-table and I have a component nested. That component is a form with 3 list on it. I'm using `onChange` callback on each list and whenever there is a change I write that down to the database. Everything works fine expect when I toggle my nested component of the react-table. If I toggle back againg to my nested component the state of the changes won't persist but the data have actually change on the database. Something I've noticed is that if I reload the page right after I've made a change on a list everything works fine.

Nested Component code:

```
constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context)
      this.state = {
       assesmentLocal: this.props.row.row.assessment_type || ''
      }
    }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (this.props.row.row.assessment_type !== nextProps.row.row.assessment_type) {
      this.setState({
        assesmentLocal: nextProps.row.row.assessment_type || '',
      });
    }
  }


  onChangeAssessmentTypeLocal (row, e) {
    // Save the new record to DB.
    this.props.onChangeAssessmentType(e.target.value, row.row.guideline_id);
    this.setState({
      assesmentLocal:e.target.value
    })
  }

  //render method
  <FormControl
    id="assessmentType"
    onChange={this.onChangeAssessmentTypeLocal.bind(this, this.props.row)}
    componentClass="select"
    placeholder="select"
    defaultValue={this.state.assesmentLocal}

  >
      <option value="INITIAL">INITIAL</option>
      <option value="GENERAL">GENERAL</option>
      <option value="SPECIALTY">SPECIALTY</option>
  </FormControl>
```

react-table Component code:

```
<ReactTable className={"-striped -highlight"}
    SubComponent={(row) => {
      return (
        <SubTable
          row={ row }
        )
      }}
  />
```

[image: Toggle component]

If I change from GENERAL to INITIAL and hide the nested component and toggle it back it will show again GENERAL but in the DB I have now INITIAL as well as in my redux store

Any ideas how I can  solve this?

**UPDATE**

this.props.row.row log:

[image]

Comment: When you say "toggle nested component" what do you mean? Are you unmounting/mounting it or just using css to hide it? If it's being unmounted/mounted then you'll need to use the `componentDidMount` method to fetch your new data.

Comment: Yes I'm mounting and unmounting, I will give it a try with the `componentDidMount` life cycle

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be with your `FormControl`, it does not have `value` props.

```
 <FormControl
    id="assessmentType"
    onChange={this.onChangeAssessmentTypeLocal.bind(this, this.props.row)}
    componentClass="select"
    placeholder="select"
    defaultValue=""
    value={this.state.assesmentLocal}
  >
```

Comment: I've done that before and its the same behavior, only when I refresh the page it will show the selected value but if I just toggle the nested component it will show the past value

Comment: Then what does the `onChangeAssessmentType` do? Can you show it as well ?

Comment: It sends the value to my actions file and there is where I inject the data to my DB.

Comment: Nope, in the react-table there is nothing to be updated

Answer (score 0):

That's maybe because not sure condition has ben set on `componentWillReceiveProps`:

have you try like this :

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 if (nextProps.row.row) {
  this.setState({
    assesmentLocal: nextProps.row.row.assessment_type || '',
  });
 }
}
```